# How to find repetitive elements(substring) in a string in R

Tags: r, string

```
a <- "ABDBBBLKDLKFFABDBOKKKMXKMABDBLPDLABDBKMKNABDBLKMXLSKMABDBOKOLKABDB"
```

How to find how many times "ABDB" is repeated in a string?

Answer (score 4):

`stringi` can do this very easily.

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(a, "ABDB")
# [1] 7
```

Comment: @DHWANIDHOLAKIA if this worked, you can accept this answer instead of the other one

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that neither requires a loop over the string nor an external package:

```
length(unlist(strsplit(paste0(a, "#"), "ABDB"))) - 1
#[1] 7
```

In this line of code, `"#"` is an auxiliary delimiter that is temporarily attached at the end of the string to make sure that occurrences of the pattern at the end are accounted for correctly.